# How to replace an element in a java.util.List with an element of another type?

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have a `list<P>` (java.util.list) .
Now I want to replace elements in `list<A>` based on two conditions.

If element == 'a' replace with 'x' and if element == 'b' replace with 'y'.
x and y are of type Q.

What is the cleanest / efficient way to do this?
Preferably, I do not want to iterate using a for loop. I can use a stream/replaceAll but that would mean violating the type of the list.

Comment: Please be more specific. Generally, the approach is to transform the entire `List<P>` into a `List<A>` or similar.

Comment: the whole of elements you have are either =a or =b? if it is not in this way , perhaps you have to use a generic list

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I can use (pseudocode)
`(list<A>).stream().forEach(r->{condition?list<B>.add(x):list<B>.add(y)})`

init list< B > before this.